# Maximize the area of a convex shape in a right isosceles triangle under some restrictions

Tags: geometry, area, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

For a given point (P) in an right isosceles triangle (see Figure), what is the curve or polygon that complies with the following:

i) One of its endpoints is at A

ii) Its other endpoint is at B

iii) It crosses through point P

iv) It cannot be outside the boundaries of triangle ABC (it can lie on its boundaries though)

v) It creates a convex shape with AB.

AND also complies with one of the following:

1. It encompasses the maximum possible area

OR

2. It encompasses the minimum possible area.

I guess that for (2) one simply needs the convex hull of the points APB. Not sure how things look like for the (1) though.

[image: Figure: Visualization of the discussed configuration]

Comment: It will be a rectangle where one side is AB and the opposite side goes through P, where the other two vertices lie on AC and AB. You could use a line through P and intersections with AB and AC and write the equation for the total area. I wonder if there is a geometrical solution.

Comment: The two solutions might be triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : (too long for a comment).

Have a look at the figure below (which is a rotated version of your figure with natural coordinates) :

[image]

Consider a mobile line passing through $P(x_0,y_0)$  with equation $y=y_0-m(x-x_0)$ (with $m>0$). It will delimitate with the coordinate axes a triangle $ODC$.

Consider the case where $0 \le x_0 \le \tfrac12, 0 \le y_0 \le \tfrac12$.

In this case, and in this case only, it is not difficult to prove that the area of triangle $ODC$ is *minimal* when
$m=\tfrac{y_0}{x_0}$. Therefore, (convex) quadrilateral $DBAC$ will have a *maximal area* (equal to $\tfrac12-2x_0y_0$). In this case, the solution curve is broken line $DBCA$.

Can you consider the other cases on this basis ?

Comment: Hi Jean, Thank you so much! I understand the rationale of the mobile line and that interest lies in placing it just in the right way so that it minimizes the red area. I also did the derivation and got the same result for the slope m. However, I do have a couple of questions. Why do we assume that the optimal curve is a straight line? Is it obvious? Also, why do you consider 0<x0<=1/2, 0<y0<=1/2? If, for example, both are equal to 1/2 then points A, B, and P lie on the same line and thus the blue area is 0 and not 1/2-1/4 as is implied by your derivation, right? Don't we want x0+y0<=1 ?Thanks!

Comment: Answers to your questions : 1) I would say that criteria (i) to (v) brings in a natural way a polygonal answer, due to the fact that convex hulls of points are optimal answers for convexity, by I recognize that a more rigorous phrasing could be given. 2) You are right, as shown by your counter example, there is an error somewhere.

Comment: I just understood : the error lies in my formula which should be $\frac12-\color{red}{2}x_0y_0$. I correct it.

Comment: I haven't detailed how I have obtained the minimal area : plainly by studying the minimum of function $f$ defined by $f(m)=(y_0+mx_0)(x_0+\frac{y_0}{m})$.

Comment: In order to fully answer one of your questions, one must consider separately the case $x_0,y_0 \in [0,1/2]$ because if for example $x_0>1/2$, point $D$ has coordinates $(2x_0,0)$, meaning that $D$ is outside triangle $AOB$... Same thing in the case $y_0>1/2$, this time, it is point $C$ which falls outside triangle $AOB$.